# Oracle / SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, null, sysdate

How to get all the rows if the no of days parameter passed is `NULL`.

Below is a part of my query:

```
and rti.creation_date >sysdate - P_DAYS
```

(`P_days` can be `null` , in which case I need to get all the rows)

will the below work :

```
and rti.creation_date >=sysdate - NVL(:P_DAYS ,
     (Select TRUNC(SYSDATE)-TRUNC(min(creation_date)) from  
apps.rcv_transactions_interface))
```

Comment: `and ( rti.creation_date >sysdate - P_DAYS or P_DAYS  IS NULL)` , this would fit better. If you can frame the query dynamically, it will be even better, if they're indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to get all the rows (as if the condition wasn't there) if P_DAYS is null?
Then you can use this code

```sql
 and (rti.creation_date >sysdate - P_DAYS or P_DAYS is null)
```

Comment: yes that is right i need to get all the rows as if the condition was not there|
P_Days is a parameter it is not any column value.
 
and (rti.creation_date >sysdate - P_DAYS or P_DAYS is null)
gives an error that the P_DAYS column does not exist

Comment: Yeah, I understood that it was a parameter. In this case the example I've provided will work as intended. When P_DAYS is null the second part of the OR will evaluate to true, when it isn't null the second part will be false and the condition will evaluate depending on the value of P_DAYS

Answer (score -1):

If you are needing the null value to be zero, then I would use `coalesce` to turn the `null` `P_DAYS` to zero as follows:

```
and rti.creation_date > sysdate - coalesce(P_DAYS,0)
```

conversely if you need it to be a large number to go back in time, substitute your large number where the zero is to get all the records.

Comment: P_Days is a NUMBER , eg: Sysdate - 7 ,
In your code if P_days is null, the code will not return any value as there is no creation date greater than Sysdate.

Comment: funny you would downgrade a potential answer when coalesce will return a zero if P_Days is null. Just because it wasn't the final answer doesn't deserve a downgrade.